# Websphere call back to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, websphere

I am using Jenkins to do a deployment to WebSphere. What I want is in the "Console Output ". To show a feedback from WebSphere if the deployment has failed or has been successful in a line. Can someone point me in a direction? How can I get a callback from WebSphere back to Jenkins saying the deployment has failed.

Is there a plugin or an API I can use or a script I can write.

I have tried to look for plugin in but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple script `ant/bat/sh` etc. to get server state. I do believe there is the script for that `severStatus.sh`. If service is running it will return `STARTED` state. 
Also you can `jython` script command `AdminControl.getAttribute(server, "state" )`.
Just read/set the state in you jenkins job and analyze a result.

See also the following link: [Checking the status of application server](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.admin.common.doc/topics/wsadmin_was_process_status_checking.html)

Answer (score 0):

For app deployment,  the AdminApp.install returns error messages upon failure.  Upon success, you can you use the AdminApp.getDeployStatus to get progress details. Use AdminApp.isAppReady to know when the app is fully deployed and ready to be started.

Documentation is here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html